# Event bubbling in kivy

Tags: python, kivy

How does event bubbling work in Kivy? Why call `super()` in a callback? For example `super(NameClass,self).on_touch_down()`.

```
class MyWidget(Widget):
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if <condition>:
            ...
            return True
        return super(MyWidget,self).on_touch_down(touch)
```

Another question, why call `super()` in this code in Scatter from comicwidgets.py:

```
 def on_touch_down(self, touch):
    if self.collide_point(touch.x, touch.y):
        self.touched = True
        self.select()
        super(DraggableWidget, self).on_touch_down(touch) # Why this call?
        return True
    return super(DraggableWidget, self).on_touch_down(touch)
```

Resource: [Code example from Chapter03_code/05-Scatter...](https://github.com/robertour/kivy-book-examples/tree/master/Chapter_04_code/05%20-%20Scatter%20-%20Multi-touching%20to%20Drag%2C%20Rotate%20and%20Scale)

Comment: Your question is a bit vague and unclear, but a general answer regarding event handling is that if you don't consume the event, then allow the event to propagate to be handled by other event handlers.  In other words, if you don't return `True` (and thusly consuming the event), you call the super to allow for others to handle the event.

Comment: holroy's answer does apply to kivy here. If the widget has no other children then it probably doesn't matter either way, but returning the super call is the proper way to make things behave properly in all situations.

Comment: +1, comments above don't really clarify whether when you do consume the event and do return True, you also need to call the base class handler ("*if you don't return True (and thusly consuming the event), you call the super to allow for others to handle the event.*" and "*returning the super call is the proper way to make things behave properly*").