# kivy touch events bubbling and overriding on_ methods

Tags: kivy

The pictures example in `/share/kivy-examples/demo/pictures` places `Image` widget in `Scatter`. I'd like to extend the example and replace `Image` with `<ImageButton@ButtonBehavior+Image>`. However, the touch events are not implemented correctly. The `ImageButton`s are press-able but the drag functionality from the original example is lost.

At first I simply changed `Image` to `<ImageButton@ButtonBehavior+Image>` in the [pictures.kv](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/examples/demo/pictures/pictures.kv) file. I see in the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.widget.html#widget-touch-event-bubbling) that I may need to (re)implement `on-press` or `on_touch_down`. To that end, I've added these methods in the Picture class:

```
class Picture(Scatter):

    source = StringProperty(None)

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            print('picture touch down')
        else:
            print('no collide in picture')
        super(Picture, self).on_touch_down(touch)
    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            print('touch move')
            super(Picture, self).on_touch_move(touch)
```

I see the print statements in the terminal. But the ImageButtons are still consuming the `on_press`, and I know this from a print statement in that event handler. I tried to re-implement `on_press` and just not do anything with `pass`, and then I had an idea of calling `self.parent.on_touch_down`, but I don't have a `touch` object to pass into it.
One idea would be to

```
class ImageButton(ButtonBehavior, Image):
    '''
    def on_press(self):
        print("button pressed")
        print()
        return super(ImageButton, self).on_press()
    '''
    def on_press(self):
        pass
```

So, say I want the `ImageButton` to only register a double-clicks, and otherwise, for the widgets to behave just like in the [example](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/examples/demo/pictures/main.py). How would I achieve that? [Somewhat related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32313468/event-bubbling-in-kivy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While there may be a way of distinguishing between a quick touch_down followed immediately by a touch_up, it is easier to show the desired functionality by letting an ImageButton press be activated with a double_tap:

```
class ImageButton(ButtonBehavior, Image):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ImageButton, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos) and touch.is_double_tap:
            self.on_press(touch)
            return True
        return False
    def on_press(self,touch):
        #whatever else you want to happen 
        return True
```